# Use apply functions to iteratively update the same object (for loop to apply function)

Tags: r

I have a matrix which I want to put into an apply function and use the location and value of each object in the matrix to select and update positions in a 3 dimensional array. I can do this very easily in a for loop, but I am curious if it is possible to do it in an apply function. I seem to be having trouble wrapping my head around that. I have some things that work, but not ideally.

```
foo <- matrix(c(3, NA, NA, 1, NA, 3, NA, 2, NA),  
       3, 3, byrow = TRUE)
bar <- array(NA, c(3, 3, 3))
```

This is the for loop that does exactly what I am looking for

```
for (i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:3){
    if (!is.na(foo[i, j])){
      bar[i, j, foo[i, j]] <- TRUE
    }
  }
}
```

This is the best that I have gotten so far. It does update the array, but it prints out a list of the assignments made at each iteration. Also if it is possible to do this without the `<<-` operator, that would be ideal.

```
fillArray <- function(x) {
  if (!is.na(foo[x[1], x[2]])) {
    bar[x[1], x[2], foo[x[1], x[2]]] <<- TRUE
  }
}

apply(expand.grid(1:3, 1:3), 1, fillArray)
```

I would like to get the same result as the for loop does.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Missed a space in the text. It's a matrix. Its there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to construct a three column `i, j, k` matrix index and then do the assignment

```
# index matrix
m1 <- cbind(as.matrix(expand.grid(1:3, 1:3)), c(foo))
bar1 <- bar # initial data
# remove the NA rows of the third column of index
bar1[m1[!is.na(m1[,3]),, drop  = FALSE]] <- TRUE
```

-checking with the output from OP

```
identical(bar, bar1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Oh, interesting indexing. Didn't know you could do something like this. Question though, it doesn't seem to work if `m1[!is.na(m1[,3]),]` is just one row. Can you explain a little bit of what is going on and why it doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @jamesguy0121  Sorry I forgot that condition.  `[` have `drop = TRUE` as default. which will drop the dimensions when there is a single row/column etc. use the `drop = FALSE`

Comment: Cool. So broader picture here, can you index any m dimensional object with an object that has m column dimensions?

Comment: If it is a 4-D, you may need to change `m1 <- cbind(as.matrix(expand.grid(1:3, 1:3, 1:3)), c(foo));bar[m1[!is.na(m1[,4]),, drop = FALSE]] <- TRUE`  I guess you got the idea

Comment: Yea I do. I was asking for general knowledge, not for what I am currently doing. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I have a follow up question for this. I was hoping to also negate a dimension in this, so like `m2 <- m1[, 3]*-1` and use that in the same way, but I get this error `Error : negative values are not allowed in a matrix subscript` which makes sense, however, this `bar[1, 1, -3]` does work as expected. Do you know what the difference here is or how I could get around it?

Comment: @jamesguy0121 I think you may need to do an `anti_join` on the full expand dataset with the subset of index to get the rows that are not in the second dataset, convert to matrix and then extract values as here